# Delete button in a template is inactive

Tags: python, django

`enter code here`I have a group_edit.html which permit to update info of a group and delete it.

Upade(save) works great but button for delete is doing nothing.
Thanks for help:
My group_edit.html:

```
{% block page %}
    <form method="POST">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 content">
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink pull-right">Save</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning pull-left"><a href="{%  url 'confirm-delete' group_id %}"></a>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'group-list' %}">Back to list</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My confirm_delete.html template:

```
{%  block title %}Delete{%  endblock %}
{%  block heading %}<h3 class="page-header-center">Object Delete</h3> {%  endblock %}

{% block page %}

    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ obj }}"?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-warning">
        <a href="group_list.html" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

my views.py:

```
def group_edit(request, group_id):
    form = GroupForm(instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GroupForm(request.POST, instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Group saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
            return redirect(group_list)

    return render(request, 'imports/group_edit.html', {
        "group_id": group_id,
        "form": form,
    })


def confirm_delete(request, group_id):
    obj = GroupForm(instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Deleted')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
        return render(request, 'imports/group_list.html')

    context = {
        "obj": obj
    }
    return render(request, "imports/confirm_delete.html", context)
```

and my urls.py:

```
path('group_edit/<int:group_id>/', views.group_edit, name='group-edit'),
path('confirm_delete/<int:group_id>/', views.confirm_delete, name='confirm-delete'),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your link, the span of `<a>` is empty. So instead of

```
<a href="{%  url 'confirm-delete' group_id %}"></a>Delete
```

it should be:

```
<a href="{%  url 'confirm-delete' group_id %}">Delete</a>
```

Probably it is better to specify the `{% url ... %}` parameters with named parameters:

```
<a href="{%  url 'confirm-delete' group_id=group_id %}">Delete</a>
```